# How to change the icon in MUI X DatePicker?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

I can't add my icon to the component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/materialuipickers-material-demo-forked-soctc

[image]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `slots` prop of `DatePicker` lets you override the inner components including the `OpenPickerIcon`, so this is how you override it:

```
import AccessibleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Accessible";

//…

<DatePicker
  slots={{
    openPickerIcon: AccessibleIcon
  }}
  {...}
```

This is the list of icon components that can be customized:

```
{
  leftArrowIcon?: elementType,
  openPickerIcon?: elementType,
  rightArrowIcon?: elementType,
  switchViewIcon?: elementType
}
```

https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/#slots

[image]

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Where did you find this info? I want to change OpenPickerButtonProps, but I don't know the syntax. Do you know it?

Comment: Also, do you know how to resolve mask warning after adding InputFormat?

Comment: @bannedFromAskingQuestions `OpenPickerButtonProps` are props of the `IconButton` at the end of the `TextField`. For example: `DatePicker OpenPickerButtonProps={{ style: { color: 'red' } }}`. `do you know how to resolve...` - you probably want to ask a separate question.

Comment: It seems that using "components" prop is now deprecated and they recommend us to use "slots" instead. 

However, this is the documentation we need in the official docs websites (with drawings). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I had troubles removing this icon. It appeared that it should be written this way:
`<DatePicker slots={{ openPickerButton: () => '' }}</DatePicker>`
Maybe it would help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the **openPickerIcon** property in **slots** of DatePicker, DateTimePicker etc to acheive it. (For adding custom svg icon)

```
 import CalendarIcon"../Components/CalendarIcon";
    
    //…
    
 <DatePicker
   slots={{
     openPickerIcon: CalendarIcon
    }}
/>
```

Create an SVG Component

```
import React from 'react';

import calendarSVG from './../calenderIcon/calendar.svg';

const CalendarIcon = () => (
  <img src={calendarSVG} alt="Calendar" />
);

export default CalendarIcon;
```