# how to customize material UI date-Picker icon for version 5?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

As I am Using Date picker of material UI version 5,I trying to replace Icon with my customized (image or svg) but not able to do so.
please help :-

i found some result for this
for changing icon but not able to apply over customized one

[How to change the icon in MUI DatePicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69569223/how-to-change-the-icon-in-mui-datepicker)

```
components={{
                  OpenPickerIcon: ?
                }}
```

Its only applying icon which are available on material UI but required some other image or svg there.

this link image contain icon which required change
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVXvz.png

Any help will be appreciated and Thankful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your image in a custom icon component. See details on custom icons [here](https://mui.com/components/icons/#svgicon).

For instance:

```
function DateIcon(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon {...props}>
      <path d="{your svg path}" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}
```

And then:

```
components={{
  OpenPickerIcon: DateIcon
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer it really helped me.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it. Be sure to upvote it and choose it as the accepted answer

Comment: Not sure why, but it was working for me when I did `openPickerIcon` rather than `OpenPickerIcon`.